# Search pattern in whole line and add a word in same line

Tags: awk, sed

My requirement is : I have 3 columns and I want to search some pattern and in column 2 and if I find that pattern then add specific word at the starting of same line.
    E.g.

```
abc boss 123
pqr madam 789
def boss 456
zxc boss 321
myb madam 345
poi boss 234
```

Now I want to search for pattern "boss" and in same line add "FOUND : " at the start of that line in same file, other content should be in tact.

Desired output :

```
FOUND : abc boss 123
pqr madam 789
FOUND : def boss 456
FOUND : zxc boss 321
myb madam 345
FOUND : poi boss 234
```

How can I do it with sed or awk commands?
Thanks in advance.
Pratik Shah

Comment: have you not tried anything?.

Comment: `patterns` are for knitting and quilts, not for software. Replace the word `pattern` in your question with either `string` or `regexp`, whichever it is you mean, and clarify if you want partial or full matches so we can help you come up with the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file
abc boss 123
pqr madam 789
def boss 456
zxc boss 321
myb madam 345
poi boss 234

$ sed '/boss/s/^/FOUND: /' file
FOUND: abc boss 123
pqr madam 789
FOUND: def boss 456
FOUND: zxc boss 321
myb madam 345
FOUND: poi boss 234

$ awk '/boss/{print "FOUND: " $0;next}1' file
FOUND: abc boss 123
pqr madam 789
FOUND: def boss 456
FOUND: zxc boss 321
myb madam 345
FOUND: poi boss 234
```

If you want to transfer a variable into `sed` or `awd`:

```
$ echo $str
boss

$ sed "/${str}/s/^/FOUND: /" file
FOUND: abc boss 123
pqr madam 789
FOUND: def boss 456
FOUND: zxc boss 321
myb madam 345
FOUND: poi boss 234

$ awk -v key="$str" '$0~key{print "FOUND: " $0;next}1' file
FOUND: abc boss 123
pqr madam 789
FOUND: def boss 456
FOUND: zxc boss 321
myb madam 345
FOUND: poi boss 234
```

Comment: Its working ! Now what should I do to pass pattern as some variable? such as I have one variable, set i "boss madam" now foreach p $i { want to pass $p in sed '/$p/s/^FOUND: /'  file}. Question is how to pass pattern as variable. Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PratikShah  Updated. Please take time read `man awk` and `man sed` as well as google them. You'll find plenty of resources for you.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/^\S\+\s\+boss\s\+/FOUND : &/' file
```

Pattern match on the second field of each line to be `boss` and insert `FOUND :` before any such match.

Comment: Please let me know, how to pass pattern as variable using foreach loop? such as I have one variable, set i "boss madam" now foreach j $i { I want to pass $j in sed "/$j/s/^FOUND: /" file} I tried it but its not working.